# I have a scalar function that returns a varchar(100) containing this "(289/2.2)*.8". How can I make the function return 105.090909090909091 instead?

Tags: function, t-sql, select, execute, scalar

In the table Health Functions I have a row for ProteinUSRDA which has the function `({weight}/2.2)*.8` . I created a scalar function that accepts the profileid (to get the weight) and a NutritionFunctionID and it will return `(289/2.2)*.8` for the selected user as a varchar(100) It would be awesome if I could get the function to return the results calculated out. Is there a way?

`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyProteinRDA]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @ProfileID int,
    @FID int
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    return (Select Replace(FFunction,'{Weight}',(Select weight from profile where profileid = @ProfileID)) from HealthFunctions where FID = 4);
END`

if I use exec the rendered function it works but I can not find a way to return it from the SQL function.

Comment: I'd change this to an *inline table valued function* and return a result set with two columns. You bind this in your query with a simple `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Evaluating an expression on-the-fly requires _dynamic SQL_. It isn't supported in a user-defined function (UDF), but it can be done in a stored procedure (SP). That precludes blending it into a query that will evaluate an expression on-the-fly per row. You can use an [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) approach and execute a SP in a cursor-based loop.

Comment: Thanks guys I did end up getting a stored proc to work. But when I tried to pull it into entity framework it complained because I used a #tmp table in the sproc and it couldn't find the fields list. I am toying with the idea of sending the function back with the profile particulars filled in and rendering the result in the controller. better Ideas?